# Snippet of current time in nvim

Tags: lua, neovim, code-snippets

I'm trying to create a snippet for vimwiki. The snippet must change `__` to current time.

```lua
local line_begin = require("luasnip.extras.expand_conditions").line_begin
return {
    s(
        {trig='__', desc="Insert current time", snippetType = "autosnippet"},
        {t("_"), t(vim.fn.system([[date +"%H:%M" | tr -d '\n']])), t({'_', ''})},
        {condition = line_begin}
    ),
}
```

Looks like it must work, but it past only fix time - the time of start of first vimwiki buffer. How to improve the snippet?

I tried to find in documentation how to do this, but have not find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Vim has a internal `strftime` function to return a date/time formatted in a way you specify with a format string (see `:help strftime`).

In your code, replace `vim.fn.system([[date +"%H:%M" | tr -d '\n']]))` by `vim.fn.strftime("%H:%M")`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It puts only fix time - the time of open buffer file.